# How to pass a copy of a slice to a function?

Tags: go, slice

I have a doubt about passing slices to functions.

If I'm not wrong the slices are passed by reference in Go, so if I do something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Println(slice)
    testSlice(slice)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

func testSlice(slice []int) {
    slice[0] = 5
    slice[4] = 1
}
```

The `testSlice` function will actually change the values in the original slice, because it was passed by reference (by default).

There is some easy way that I can directly pass a copy of the slice to the `testSlice` function?

Sure I can do something like this to create a copy of the slice:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Println(slice)
    testSlice(slice)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}

func testSlice(slice []int) {
    var newSlice []int
    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
        newSlice = append(newSlice, slice[i])
    }
    newSlice[0] = 5
    newSlice[4] = 1
}
```

But it needs to go through all values in the original slice to copy each of them, and it doesn't seem to be a great solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a built in function, `copy`, `func copy(dst, src []T) int` which is probably what you're looking for. It copies a slice of any type into another slice.

From the [docs](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals):

> The copy function supports copying between slices of different lengths (it will copy only up to the smaller number of elements). In addition, copy can handle source and destination slices that share the same underlying array, handling overlapping slices correctly.

So

```
list := []string{"hello", "world"}
newList := make([]string, len(list))
n := copy(newList, list)
// n is the number of values copied
```

Will copy `list` into a new slice `newList`, which share values but not the reference in memory. The `int` `copy` returns is the number of values copied.

---

For an alternative way, from Kostix's comment, you can append the slice to an empty slice. Which is kind of like copying it. It might not be idiomatic, but it allows you to pass the slice into a `func` as a copy, *sort of*. If you do this, I recommend copious comments.

```
thisFuncTakesSliceCopy( append([]string(nil), list...) )
```

To append a slice to another slice, remember the ellipses (`...`).

Comment: Thanks @Nevermore, this is a more elegant way to copy the `slice`. Just to make sure. There is no way that I can pass a `slice` copy directly to a function? The only way is to create a new `slice` manually and copy the values from the original `slice`? I'm just asking it because I'm coming from `C++` and there I can pass vectors by reference or by value.

Comment: @KelvinSalton go has absolutely no notion of "pass by reference". Everything is passed by value. A slice is a descriptor into an underlying array. If you want a copy of that part of the array you have to make a copy. Go's focus is not "elegant" or "syntactic sugar" but "explicit":

Comment: It's also possible to do `b := append([]byte(nil), a...)` which appends the whole `a` to a nil slice — essentially producing a copy which gets assigned to `b`.